# gstreamer plugin error - No such element or plugin 'pocketsphinx' (Mac)

Tags: python, plugins, gstreamer, cmusphinx

I tried to follow [this tutorial](https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/gstreamer/) but failed.
I am confused about which string to assign to **GST_PLUGIN_PATH**.
In other words, this is my current GST_PLUGIN_PATH( according to some searching on forums)

> usr/local/Cellar/gstreamer/1.14.4/

But I also have tried this string because the mentioned tutorial made me do so:

> /usr/local/Cellar/cmu-pocketsphinx/0.8/lib/python2.7/site-packages/

the "pocketsphinx.so" file is inside the latter one while it is not inside the former one.

Neither of the above strings works;

```
gst-inspect-1.0 pocketsphinx
```

gave me this message no matter which value I assigned to **GST_PLUGIN_PATH**:

> No such element or plugin 'pocketsphinx'

Previously, I also copy the .pc files.

- $cd /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
- $cp gstreamer-1.0.pc
  /usr/local/Cellar/cmu-pocketsphinx/0.8/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
- $cp gstreamer-base-1.0.pc /usr/local/Cellar/cmu-pocketsphinx/0.8/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
- $cp gstreamer-plugins-base-1.0.pc
  /usr/local/Cellar/cmu-pocketsphinx/0.8/lib/python2.7/site-packages/

Please help, thank you.

Comment: The plugin could have been blacklisted due to missing dependencies too. I would check with `otool -L` whether all dependencies could be found first. Then check whether any plugins may have been blacklisted.

Comment: @FlorianZwoch if this same situation happens at ubuntu(instead of mac), then which command should I use to check dependencies? thank you.

Comment: `ldd` can be helpful in this case.

Comment: For other people who need help,  **gst-inspect-1.0 -b**，helped me see the blacklist of gstreamer.